# Accessing component methods with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am trying to make a simple carousel by following this documentation [Carousel](https://ant.design/components/carousel/)

Working [example](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods/)

how can I translate above to use functional components/hooks.

I have been trying to bind next() within an onClick Button however I can't seem to get it to work. How can I correctly access the next method and bind it within my button?

```js
<Carousel ref={c => (this.slider = c)} >
  <div>
    <h3><Button onClick={() => this.carousel.next()}>1</Button></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3><Button onClick={() => this.carousel.prev()}>2</Button></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
</Carousel>
```

Comment: @codekaizer yes I know I can click on the dots to transition to another tab but I would like to customize the navigation style and bind my next/previous to a button. Current example above does not work. This is just purely for self-education on how to access Methods from the documentation. Please see example link above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the [`next()`](https://ant.design/components/carousel/#Methods) api from the `<Carousel />` `ref`. With function component, you can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook, like this:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Carousel } from "antd";

export function App() {
  const carousel = useRef(null);
  function next() {
    carousel.current.next();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Carousel ref={carousel}>
        <div>
          <h3>1</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>2</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>3</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>4</h3>
        </div>
      </Carousel>
      <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-react-ref-hook-next-492gv

Comment: Thanks for a clean example :)

Comment: @MoshFeu How can I acces the `next` declared in `App` from a parent component? `<AppWrapper><App></App></AppWrapper>` In this example I need to call `next` from `AppWrapper`.

Comment: @BrunoFinger I guess that it's not related to `Carousel`. Anyway, you can pass it to App as prop. In `AppWrapper` - `<App doSomthing={() => console.log('do something') />`.